# C# console same output from multi batch files

Tags: c#, batch-file, console-application, messaging

I need a console application to record some events from an other external application.
Console application purpose is to display on screen what external app is doing at each steps.
This external application only can call an exe with arguments.

Goal is:

- External do some job
- Ex call Console with args to display
- External do some other job
- Ex call Console with args to display
- ...

But Console application is closed an reopened at each call.
I need a trick to have a console app waiting for messages and displaying it without closing, but I really dont now where to start looking at.

It may be very ligthweight solution, without any install required.

Thanks.

**Edit**

the external app (silently running) can only do a command "run program ..." at each step (a command line to exe with parameters).

At each step, I must send to my console app some informations to write ouput to user and little more things. I want a unique  output, not a new Console app at each step...

The main idea is to have a background running console app waiting messages from the external app to send informations.

Its kind of lauch console app with paramters, dont stop it and recall same with new parameters, but i dont think it is possible.

I cant install tools on the machines,  becauses solution may be deployed on many devices in my company, i cant install services or databases on each..

What kind of solution will you use? Can an console application wait for incoming messages and catch them?

Comment: I don't see any question marks. What exactly is your problem? What have you already tried?

Comment: Open `cmd.exe`, run apps, write to stdout, don't close `cmd.exe`? :)

Comment: myconsoleapp <stuff to run> so it takes parameters, and runs it, and saves results?

Comment: I ll update my question.

Comment: (sry i m new on using stackoverflow^^)
 I dont now how to have my console application always running and wait for new args towrite new messages.
 but if I redo it the application will call a new cmd.exe.
I need to promt all information during all the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different approaches to this;

- Inter Process Communication - May be overkill here
- Shared Files - Simple but error prone
- Other shared storage (Database or Messaging Service) - Would probably be my recommended way

Using the Database method your application will insert 'logs' of each job into a database table. The Console application can then loop with a simple While loop, reading rows and displaying them. This is more scalable as you can use the logs to, for example, restart jobs etc.

Comment: I updated my question because I saw some info are missing :) 
Shared files :In my case each step of external program can take a while, so I cant make a time out and I can possibly have an infinite loop!
Inter process:  is it "resource friendly"? 
Database : I cant install database on each device.
I ll look to messaging services, I never implemented this.
If it match to my requirements I ll validate your answer thanks!

Comment: Using a database - you would use one central database, and all clients would simply communicate with it over network, so you wouldn't need to install a database on each machine... The principal is the same using shared files though, you would simply add the data to be shown to the database or file, and the console app would simply periodically check the database or file and display any new data that had been added since it last checked.

Comment: Sorry I missed an other information, it must work in an offline state! Otherwise a centralised DB with services is a good solution.
I just need a simple way to have communication between my 2 apps without external tools , and a unique console output, but it really more difficult than I thank at begining.

Comment: Ahh I see, the shared files method would still work fine... You would simply write your output to a file somewhere, and the console app would read this file periodically, showing any NEW lines that have been added to the file since it last checked. This should be very simple to implement. Look into the System.IO.File methods provided in the .NET libraries.

Comment: It s the easiest way to do it, as you say other options are overkill. I have coupled it with a System.IO.FileSystemWatcher, it work like a charme, thanks.

Comment: Well done - Glad to hear! Please consider marking my answer as the accepted one if it helped you out :)

Comment: (I was searching 1 min before understanding I can click on check button sry! Going for a coffee...)